# what happened when use '-race' flag in go build

Tags: go

I am confusing for following code, what's the difference between `go run`  with `go run -race`, Does the `-race` will change the program behavior?

```golang
// test.go
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := make(chan string)

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
            c <- "hello there"
        }
    }()

    for msg := range c {
        fmt.Println(msg)
    }
}
```

when `go run test.go`, result is :

```
hello there
hello there
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
        /Users/donghui6/go/src/jd.com/iaas-sre/test/test.go:14 +0xf4
exit status 2
```

when `go run -race test.go`, program will hang as following:

```
hello there
hello there
```

so, who can tell me what happened when use `-race` flag

Comment: You have used the past tense in "What happened ..." so I assume this code happened to crash when build with the `-race` flag in some previous version of Go and does not crash when build with the `-race` flags using some newer version of Go you did not care to tell us, right?

Comment: Anyway, there are two things to it. First, the program does really have a bug (it does not terminate while not able to do any useful work) but the Go runtime is not _required_ to detect such a case and do anything (this is not mandated by the language spec). Second, this behaviour is still usesul, so _may be_ you did find a bug. It's hard to tell as your question is missing many useful details to make attempts to do more deep analysis disting from mere handwaving.

Comment: So the question is why the deadlock isn't detected anymore when the race detector is enabled?

Comment: I have tried my best to update the details @kostix

Comment: No, my question is why the same piece of code behaves differently if the -race option is used at compile time @Peter

Comment: But the only difference in behavior is that the deadlock isn't detected when -race is given.

Comment: This is where I get confused. The purpose of -race should be to detect Race Conditions at runtime@Peter

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> what happen[s] when use '-race' flag in go build

Then the program is built with the so called "race detector" enabled. Dataraces are a programming error and any program with a datarace is invalid and its behaviour is undefined. You must never write code with data races.

A data race is when two or more goroutines read and write to the same memory without proper synchronisation. Data races happen but are a *major* fault of the programmer.

The race detector detects unsynchronised read/writes to the same memory and reports them as a failure (which it is). Note that if the race detector detects a data race your code **is** **buggy** even if it runs "properly" without -race.

The race detector is not on always because detecting data races slows down execution drastically.

Comment: While you're 100% correct regarding the race detector, the OP's code does not have a data race, and a deadlock is not an example of a data race (at least not _directly)._ So to me, this is indeed something which would worth reporting upstream: while the Go runtime is not required to take any special action when it detects an easily detectable ("total") deadlock), what it currently does is useful, and I'd say it would be useful if it would work under `-race` as well.

Comment: @kostix When I wrote the answer the question was literally "what happened when use -race flag". This was edited to a version with more focus on deadlock detection with and without the race detector. Thats why the answer is correct but no longer a good match for the edited question.